# Filtering Nodes from a list of values in gremlin query

Tags: gremlin, titan

Suppose I have a list of attribute values as an ArrayList, How can I filter nodes by the values in the list.

Is something like this possible...

```
g.V().filter {it.get().value("name") in list}
```

also is it compatible with TinkerPop 2.x

Comment: What graph database are you using?

Comment: Titan graph database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [`filter()`](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Gremlin-Steps#filter-based-steps) step can work:

```
gremlin> [ 'Titan' : Titan.version(), 'TinkerPop' : Gremlin.version()]
==>Titan=0.5.4
==>TinkerPop=2.5.0
gremlin> g = TitanFactory.open('inmemory')
==>titangraph[inmemory:[127.0.0.1]]
gremlin> v0 = g.addVertex().setProperty('name', 'amith')
==>null
gremlin> v1 = g.addVertex().setProperty('name', 'jason')
==>null
gremlin> v2 = g.addVertex().setProperty('name', 'stephen')
==>null
gremlin> g.commit()
==>null
gremlin> l = ['amith', 'jason', 'florian'] // list to match
==>amith
==>jason
==>florian
gremlin> g.V().filter{ l.contains(it.getProperty('name')) }.map()
15:06:30 WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx  - Query requires iterating over all vertices [()]. For better performance, use indexes
==>{name=amith}
==>{name=jason}
```

Keep in mind that Titan 0.5.4 is quite dated (released in Feb 2015), and it depends on TinkerPop 2.5.0 (released in Apr 2014). Titan and [TinkerPop 2.x](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/incubator-tinkerpop/master/docs/static/images/not-tinkerpop3-gremlin.png) are no longer under active development.

You should consider moving on to [JanusGraph](https://janusgraph.org), which is a fork of Titan, has an active and open community, and is keeping current with the latest releases of [Apache TinkerPop 3.x](https://tinkerpop.apache.org).

Answer (score 8):

You can simply use the [`has`](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#has-step) step for the filtering as it can take a list of values thanks to the `within` predicate:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> names=['josh','peter']; g.V().has('name', within(names))
==>v[4]
==>v[6]
```

edit: My answer doesn't really address the question anymore as it now asks for a TinkerPop 2 solution. I'm still leaving it here in case anyone stumbles upon this question while looking for a solution for TinkerPop 3.

Comment: hi, is it compatible with tinkerpop 2.x

Comment: I don't know as I haven't used TinkerPop 2 for years. Would be good to state in your question when it's specific to TinkerPop 2 as TinkerPop 3.0.0 was released [exactly 3 years ago](https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/master/CHANGELOG.asciidoc#tinkerpop-300-release-date-july-9-2015).

Comment: How to deal with situation where `names` is a dynamic collection from a previous step? e.g.  [previous_step] outV().store('names') .by('name')   then use it in subsequent traversal as  outV().has('name', within(names))

Comment: @Anil_M: Please start a new question for that as it deserves its own answer in my opinion so more people can find it.

Comment: @FlorianHockmann - I did ask question and got the answer, Its mentioned in my response : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75903169/search-for-value-by-key-within-dynamic-collection

Answer (score 0):

If the arrayList is part of existing traversal collected using `store`, you can use something like below.
Listing here in case someone runs into this situation.(like I did)

Say you have collection `names` collected in previous traversals and want to filter vertices based on that in subsequent traversal / steps.

```
g.V().out().store('names').by('name')
      .out()
      .where(within('names'))
        .by('name')
        .by()
    .dedup()
     ...... further traversal
```

The above solution is derived from my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75903169/search-for-value-by-key-within-dynamic-collection) answered by @Kelvin Lawrence