# search for value by key within dynamic collection

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, gremlinpython

I am looking to extend discussion held [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765219/filtering-nodes-from-a-list-of-values-in-gremlin-query/50773482#comment133881117_50773482)  about filtering vertices based on property value from  collection.
However, in my case the collection is dynamic e.g. generated using `store`

e.g.

following works using a static list `['red', 'green']`.
I am able to filter out vertices with just `'red', 'green'` as value in property `'color_name'`.

```
g.V().out().as('colors').store('color_list').by('name') 
.out()
.out().has('color_name', within(['red', 'green']))
.dedup()
.path()
```

but if I try to use collection from previous store it doesnt work.
color_list has same members as above. = `['red', 'green']`

```
 g.V().out().as('colors').store('color_list').by('name')
    .out()
    .out().has('color_name', within('color_list'))
    .dedup()
    .path()
```

I must be missing something. My understanding of gremlin traversal is still in infancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that to work you need to use a `where` step. The `has` step will interpret `'color_list'` as a literal string and not the label for something named earlier in the query. The query needs to be along these lines:

```java
 g.V().out().as('colors').store('color_list').by('name')
      .out()
      .out()
      .where(within('color_list'))
        .by('color_name')
        .by()
    .dedup()
    .path()
```

Comment: That works perfectly.  Many thanks for quick response. i don't yet understand .`where(within('color_list'))
  .by('color_name').by() `  logic - so we are looking within `color_list` collection with data filtered  on `color_name` from previous traversal using first by ? why do we need a second by() ? Is there a reference documentation to understand it better. thx.

Comment: Think of it this way -  `within` needs two values. The item flowing into the step, and the list of things we want to check against. The first `by` represents the item flowing in - in this case a vertex.  The first `by`  lists the property on that vertex to use. The second `by` tells the `where` step what to use for the 'color_list'. As in this case that is the list itself we can just use an empty `by()`. It is shorthand for `by(select('color_list'))` essentially. We need to provide two `by` because otherwise Gremlin will try to round robin the first one, and that will not work in this case.

Comment: Hi , QQ: how do I supply multiple attributes to the first by() . e.g. 'color_name'  or 'color_type'. thx. I tried or, its giving error.

Comment: Will only one or other of `color_name` or `color_type` be present on any given vertex?

Comment: yes, I am thinking of using OR in case one of the property is missing, in that case the query can look for next one. thx.

Comment: Rather than use `or`, you can use `union`. Using the air-routes data set as an example: 
```
 g.V('1','2','3').values('region').fold().as('r').
   V('8','9','10').
   where(within('r')).
     by(union(values('x'),values('region'))).
     by().
   values('code','region')
```
In this case 'x' does not exist.